# Swift - Get letters only from String

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get letters only from String in Swift.

For example:

```
let str = "he4ll5663#$#0o"
print(str.letters) // prints hello
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do it using `filter` on the `unicodeScalars` of the `String`:

```
extension String {
    var letters: String {
        return String(unicodeScalars.filter(CharacterSet.letters.contains))
    }
}

let str = "he4ll5663#$#0o"
print(str.letters)  // hello
```

Thanks @MartinR for the suggestion to avoid using `first!` (in my original answer) by changing the `filter` to the `unicodeScalars` of the `String`.

Comment: What about `String(unicodeScalars.filter(CharacterSet.letters.contains))` – to avoid the `first!` ?

Comment: @MartinR, thanks.  I like that.  I was looking at various ways of getting rid of `first` and force unwraps.

Comment: Operating on the Unicode scalars is problematic as well: `let str = "a \u{301}b" ; print(str, str.letters)`  prints `a ́b áb`

Comment: @MartinR, that is interesting.  The current version of my answer and OP's answer both print `áb`.  My original version printed `ab`. Any opinion what the correct result should be?

Comment: I noticed this while reading https://forums.swift.org/t/string-hygiene/12826, where similar problems are discussed. In this case `ab` is probably the correct answer, but I am not sure if that works correctly in all cases. The problem seems to be that the "is a letter" property is defined for Unicode Scalars, not for `Character`s.

Comment: @MartinR, do you know of any programming languages that handle this better?  Swift is trying, but not quite succeeding, so far.

Comment: @LeoDabus, try that with `let str = "Español"`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I don't consider capitol `E` a special character ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5.1 or later**

Swift 5 or later we can use [Character properties](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0221-character-properties.md).
Swift 5.1 or later we can [omit the return keyword](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0255-omit-return.md)

---

```
extension Bool {
    var negated: Bool { !self }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func removeNonLetters() { removeAll(where: \.isLetter.negated) }
    var letters: Self { filter(\.isLetter) }
}
```

---

usage:

```
var str3 = "a \u{301}b"
str3.letters              // "ab"
str3                      // "a ́b"
str3.removeNonLetters()   // "ab"
str3                      // "ab"
```

Answer (score 1):

So I couldn't find it anywhere on the web, so i'll post my answer, hope it'll help anyone:

```
extension String {

    var letters: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.letters.inverted)
            .joined()
    }

}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Real quick:

`iAmAString.filter { $0.isLetter}`

and get on with your life.